# Proof that $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by

\begin{align*}
\varphi(r)=\begin{bmatrix}1&&r\\0&&1\end{bmatrix},\ \forall r\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align*}

I was wondering if showing that
\begin{align*}
\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)
\end{align*}
was a sufficient enough proof. I used to think it was, but I'm not entirely sure at the moment. I believe it would be a sufficient enough proof if the mapping was $\varphi:GL_2(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ and I think I just implicitly took it to be true for the original mapping I'm asking about. I know that I could simply show
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}1&&0\\a&&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&&0\\b&&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&&0\\a+b&&1\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
and that this would be a sufficient enough proof. But I guess I'm just curious if the first one is ok.

Comment: The definition of $\varphi$ and your matrix multplication are inconsistent.

Comment: Genuine curiosity: what made you think looking at determinants is useful here? $\det(\phi(r)) = 1$ regardless of what $r$ was, so all the interesting information gets destroyed as soon as you take determinants. That doesn't bode well for the proof strategy...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you think that this would be sufficient. Proving that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ is sufficient (and necessary) to show that $\det: \text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is a homomorphism.

This has nothing to do with the homomorphism $\varphi$ you described.

Also, it would not be a sufficient argument for (just any) $\varphi:\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ being a homomorphism, but just the function $A \mapsto \det(A)$.

Comment: Nitpicky, but the determinant is a homomorphism into $\mathbb{R}^\times$ not into $\mathbb{R}$ as it is compatible with the multiplicative not the additive structure. Otherwise your answer is spot-on.

Comment: Completely right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just the fact that

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & r\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & s\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & r+s\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$

which is simple enough by direct computation, suffices to see that $$\phi(r)\cdot \phi(s) = \phi(r+s)$$ and so the map $\phi$ is a homomorphism from the additive group $\Bbb R$ to the multiplicative group $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb R)$.

The fact about determinants is a general fact and says nothing about $\phi$, and for all $r$, $\det(\phi(r))= 1$ which shows that the homomorphism $\det$ (to the multiplicative group $\Bbb R^\ast$) is trivial on the image of $\phi$.